# Apache Spark stuck in "loading" state

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is job I'm running from Spark shell :

```
  val l = sc.parallelize((1 to 5000000).toList)  
  val m = l.map(m => m*23)                    
  m.take(5000000)
```

Workers appear to be "LOADING" state :

[image]

What is "LOADING" state ?

Update :

As I understand `take` will perform job on cluster and then return results to Driver. So "LOADING" state equates to the data being loaded onto driver ?

Comment: @eliasah where do you see `5,000,000 million` entries ?

Comment: m.take(5000000)  creates a Array of 5000000 entries!

Comment: thats `5 million` ... :P

Comment: Sorry, big fingers! :P

Comment: @eliasah thanks but my question refers meaning of "loading" state

Comment: I dont have an answer, but in my case(spark streaming app) i have 5 workers and 3 of them are loading and the other 2 are running. It is pretty weird but I am sure that all of them are performing some computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that if you do something like this,

```
(1 to 5000000 ).toList
```

You are bound to encounter `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

This happens when JVM realizes that it is spending too much time in `Grabage Collection`. By default the JVM is configured to throw this error if you are spending `more than 98% of the total time` in `GC` and after the `GC` `less than 2%` of the `heap` is recovered.

In this particular case you are creating `new instance` of `List` for every iteration, ( `immutability`, so each time a `new instance` of `List` is returned ). Which means each iteration leaves an useless instance of `List`, and for `List` with size in millions, it will take lot of memory and trigger `GC` very frequently. Also, each time `GC` has to free lot of memory hence take lot of time.

This ultimately leads to error - `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded`.

**What happens if this was not there ?** -> This means that the little amount GC was able to clean will be quickly filled again thus forcing GC to restart the cleaning process again.This forms a vicious cycle where the CPU is 100% busy with GC and no actual work can be done. The application will face extreme slowdowns – operations which used to be completed in milliseconds will now likely to take minutes to finish.

This is a pre-emptive fail-fast safeguard implemented in JVM's.

You can disable this safeguard by using following Java Option.

```
-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

But I will strongly recommend **NOT** doing this.

And even if you disable this feature ( or if your Spark-Cluster avoids this `to some extent` by allocating large heap space ), some thing like

```
(1 to 5000000 ).toList
```

will take a long long time.

Also, I have a strong feeling that systems like `Spark` which are supposed to be running multiple jobs are configured ( by default, may be you can override ) to `pause` or `reject` such jobs as soon as they realize extreme GC which can lead to starvation of other jobs. And this may be the main reason your job is always loading.

You can get a lot of relief by using a `mutable List` and appending values to it with a for loop. Now you can parallelise your mutable list.

```
val mutableList = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList.empty[ Int ]

for ( i <- 1 to 5000000 ) {
  mutableList.append( i )
}

val l = sc.parallelize( mutableList )
```

But even this will lead to multiple ( but many times less severe ) memeory allocations( hence GC exectuions ) whenever the `List` is `half-full`, which result in `memory relocation` of whole `List` with double of previously allocated memory.